# Is there a way to calculate the REAL height of a font?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've ran across a situation where text doesn't align properly using the vertical centering. Especially when the font size is large (i.e. 40). I can fix it by applying a negative margin to the top, but is there a way to programmatically calculate the amount of the margin? I tried getting the FormattedText, but the numbers just don't match up with what's drawn on the screen.

```
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Width="46" Height="46" UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Gadugi" Margin="0,-4,0,0" FontSize="36" Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
```

The -4 fixes this case, but how would I calculate the -4 code wise? Since it's different on a per font / per font size basis.

The numbers just don't seem to match up with what's in FormattedText.

Comment: Sounds like you're just looking for `LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"` but I'm not familiar with that font so just a comment. Though `BaseLineOffset` is what I'm guessing the mentioned margin would be applied.

Comment: @ChrisW. It happens with pretty much any font. If you take off the margin and pick your favorite font, it won't be vertically centered in the border.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using geometry transformation like this:

```
FormattedText text = new FormattedText("Your text",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface("Arial"), 20, Brushes.Black);
Geometry geometry = text.BuildGeometry(new Point());
double height = geometry.Bounds.Bottom - geometry.Bounds.Top;
```

However this will result in the height of the string you input. This means that "abc" is shorter in height than "ABC" which is shorter than "Ay"

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure that would look right as "A" and "a" next to each other would be centered differently. I guess I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the fudge factor in code so it'll work with any font / font size.

Comment: When I do this on "A", I get height = 25 and text.Extent = 27, so that's not giving me the -4 fudge factor.

Comment: Hmm... I guess the 27 is the right height of the number... I guess what I really need is to know what TextBlock is centering around because its not centering about text.Extent. Seems like its centering around something smaller.

Comment: Hmm again... I tried with FontSize 16, 36 and 40. Oddly 16 & 36 require a fudge factor of -4, but 40 randomly needs -7. I tried a few between 16 & 36 and they are all -4. I wonder if it has something to do with the font size being more then the border at 48.

Comment: May be the interline squeezed inside layouting except when Thérèse is not enough space for the font itself. Eventually try to set LineHeight to font size.

Comment: By the way setting LineStackingStrategy to BlockLineHeight makes textblock to size itself differently. I didn't have enough time to understand the logic yet.